# Determine the key of a song by its chords

Tags: javascript, node.js, music-notation

How can I programmatically find the key of a song just by knowing the chord sequence of the song?
I asked some people how they would determine the key of a song and they all said they do it 'by ear' or by 'trial and error' and by telling if a chord resolves a song or not... For the average musician that is probably fine, but as a programmer that really isn't the answer that I was looking for.

So I started looking for music related libraries to see if anyone else has written an algorithm for that yet. But although I found a really big library called 'tonal' on GitHub: https://danigb.github.io/tonal/api/index.html I couldn't find a method that would accept an array of chords and return the key.

My language of choice will be JavaScript (NodeJs), but I'm not necessarily looking for a JavaScript answer. Pseudo code or an explanation that can be translated into code without too much trouble would be totally fine.

As some of you mentioned correctly, the key in a song can change. I'm not sure if a change in key could be detected reliably enough. So, for now let's just say, I'm looking for an algorithm that makes a good approximation on the key of a given chord sequence.

...
After looking into the circle of fifths, I think I found a pattern to find all chords that belong to each key. I wrote a function `getChordsFromKey(key)` for that. And by checking the chords of a chord sequence against every key, I can create an array containing probabilities of how likely it is that the key matches the given chord sequence: `calculateKeyProbabilities(chordSequence)`. And then I added another function `estimateKey(chordSequence)`, which takes the keys with the highest probability-score and then checks if the last chord of the chord sequence is one of them. If that is the case, it returns an array containing only that chord, otherwise it returns an array of all chords with the highest probability-score.
This does an OK job, but it still doesn't find the correct key for a lot of songs or returns multiple keys with equal probabililty. The main problem being chords like `A5, Asus2, A+, A°, A7sus4, Am7b5, Aadd9, Adim, C/G` etc. that are not in the circle of fifths. And the fact that for instance the key `C` contains the exact same chords as the key `Am`, and `G` the same as `Em` and so on...
Here is my code:

```js
'use strict'
const normalizeMap = {
    "Cb":"B",  "Db":"C#",  "Eb":"D#", "Fb":"E",  "Gb":"F#", "Ab":"G#", "Bb":"A#",  "E#":"F",  "B#":"C",
    "Cbm":"Bm","Dbm":"C#m","Eb":"D#m","Fbm":"Em","Gb":"F#m","Ab":"G#m","Bbm":"A#m","E#m":"Fm","B#m":"Cm"
}
const circleOfFifths = {
    majors: ['C', 'G', 'D', 'A',  'E',  'B',  'F#', 'C#', 'G#','D#','A#','F'],
    minors: ['Am','Em','Bm','F#m','C#m','G#m','D#m','A#m','Fm','Cm','Gm','Dm']
}

function estimateKey(chordSequence) {
    let keyProbabilities = calculateKeyProbabilities(chordSequence)
    let maxProbability = Math.max(...Object.keys(keyProbabilities).map(k=>keyProbabilities[k]))
    let mostLikelyKeys = Object.keys(keyProbabilities).filter(k=>keyProbabilities[k]===maxProbability)

    let lastChord = chordSequence[chordSequence.length-1]

    if (mostLikelyKeys.includes(lastChord))
         mostLikelyKeys = [lastChord]
    return mostLikelyKeys
}

function calculateKeyProbabilities(chordSequence) {
    const usedChords = [ ...new Set(chordSequence) ] // filter out duplicates
    let keyProbabilities = []
    const keyList = circleOfFifths.majors.concat(circleOfFifths.minors)
    keyList.forEach(key=>{
        const chords = getChordsFromKey(key)
        let matchCount = 0
        //usedChords.forEach(usedChord=>{
        //    if (chords.includes(usedChord))
        //        matchCount++
        //})
        chords.forEach(chord=>{
            if (usedChords.includes(chord))
                matchCount++
        })
        keyProbabilities[key] = matchCount / usedChords.length
    })
    return keyProbabilities
}

function getChordsFromKey(key) {
    key = normalizeMap[key] || key
    const keyPos = circleOfFifths.majors.includes(key) ? circleOfFifths.majors.indexOf(key) : circleOfFifths.minors.indexOf(key)
    let chordPositions = [keyPos, keyPos-1, keyPos+1]
    // since it's the CIRCLE of fifths we have to remap the positions if they are outside of the array
    chordPositions = chordPositions.map(pos=>{
        if (pos > 11)
            return pos-12
        else if (pos < 0)
            return pos+12
        else
            return pos
    })
    let chords = []
    chordPositions.forEach(pos=>{
        chords.push(circleOfFifths.majors[pos])
        chords.push(circleOfFifths.minors[pos])
    })
    return chords
}

// TEST

//console.log(getChordsFromKey('C'))
const chordSequence = ['Em','G','D','C','Em','G','D','Am','Em','G','D','C','Am','Bm','C','Am','Bm','C','Em','C','D','Em','Em','C','D','Em','Em','C','D','Em','Em','C','D','Am','Am','Em','C','D','Em','Em','C','D','Em','Em','C','D','Em','Em','C','D','Em','Em','C','D','Em','Em','C','D','Em','Em','C','D','Em','Em','C','D','Em']

const key = estimateKey(chordSequence)
console.log('Example chord sequence:',JSON.stringify(chordSequence))
console.log('Estimated key:',JSON.stringify(key)) // Output: [ 'Em' ]
```

Comment: Actually you cant. Dur and Moll can only be differed by feeling ( or some special notations ).

Comment: In general, it's not something can can simply compute precisely. If you refer to chords by roman numeral and use lower case for minor, upper for major, the pattern is basically: I ii iii IV V vi vii(dim). As @Jonasw points out, there is a minor sequence: i ii(dim) III iv v VI VIII, which looks like a major sequence rotated by 2 chords (this refers to the *relative minor* of a *major* scale). Even more complicated is if altered chords are used. You might be able, though, to make a heuristic guess at what the key *likely* is. Look up "common chord progressions" in Google. Very common is I IV V.

Comment: A song, by the way, doesn't always start on I. And some songs change keys.

Comment: @lurker and it often ends on the root (of course not always)

Comment: @KScandrett often, but you can't count on it. I've written a few songs and I often like ending on a non-root chord. :) I think the point is, there's no hard-and-fast rule since it's art.

Comment: Here are the chords, in order, of an example song: Bm G Bm A Bm G Bm A G Em Bm F#m G Em D A.... it ultimately ends on an F#m. The key is D. The D chord appears only a couple of times in the song. A key can be quite ambiguous. Jazz thrives heavily on the ambiguity of harmony. So this problem gets even more complicated with more complex chords (m7, aug7, m7b5, etc).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs to another SE site, data science or crossvalidated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach would be to find all the notes being played, and compare to the signature of different scales and see which is the best match.

Normally a scale signature is pretty unique. A natural minor scale will have the same notes as a major scale (that is true for all the modes), but generally when we say minor scale we mean the harmonic minor scale, which has a specific signature.

So comparing what notes are in the chords with your different scales should give you a good estimate. And you could refine by adding some weight to different notes (for example the ones that come up the most, or the first and last chords, the tonic of each chord, etc.)

This seems to handle most basic cases with some accuracy:

```js
'use strict'
const allnotes = [
  "C", "C#", "D", "Eb", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "Ab", "A", "Bb", "B"
]

// you define the scales you want to validate for, with name and intervals
const scales = [{
  name: 'major',
  int: [2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11]
}, {
  name: 'minor',
  int: [2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11]
}];

// you define which chord you accept. This is easily extensible,
// only limitation is you need to have a unique regexp, so
// there's not confusion.

const chordsDef = {
  major: {
    intervals: [4, 7],
    reg: /^[A-G]$|[A-G](?=[#b])/
  },
  minor: {
    intervals: [3, 7],
    reg: /^[A-G][#b]?[m]/
  },
  dom7: {
    intervals: [4, 7, 10],
    reg: /^[A-G][#b]?[7]/
  }
}

var notesArray = [];

// just a helper function to handle looping all notes array
function convertIndex(index) {
  return index < 12 ? index : index - 12;
}


// here you find the type of chord from your 
// chord string, based on each regexp signature
function getNotesFromChords(chordString) {

  var curChord, noteIndex;
  for (let chord in chordsDef) {
    if (chordsDef[chord].reg.test(chordString)) {
      var chordType = chordsDef[chord];
      break;
    }
  }

  noteIndex = allnotes.indexOf(chordString.match(/^[A-G][#b]?/)[0]);
  addNotesFromChord(notesArray, noteIndex, chordType)

}

// then you add the notes from the chord to your array
// this is based on the interval signature of each chord.
// By adding definitions to chordsDef, you can handle as
// many chords as you want, as long as they have a unique regexp signature
function addNotesFromChord(arr, noteIndex, chordType) {

  if (notesArray.indexOf(allnotes[convertIndex(noteIndex)]) == -1) {
    notesArray.push(allnotes[convertIndex(noteIndex)])
  }
  chordType.intervals.forEach(function(int) {

    if (notesArray.indexOf(allnotes[noteIndex + int]) == -1) {
      notesArray.push(allnotes[convertIndex(noteIndex + int)])
    }

  });

}

// once your array is populated you check each scale
// and match the notes in your array to each,
// giving scores depending on the number of matches.
// This one doesn't penalize for notes in the array that are
// not in the scale, this could maybe improve a bit.
// Also there's no weight, no a note appearing only once
// will have the same weight as a note that is recurrent. 
// This could easily be tweaked to get more accuracy.
function compareScalesAndNotes(notesArray) {
  var bestGuess = [{
    score: 0
  }];
  allnotes.forEach(function(note, i) {
    scales.forEach(function(scale) {
      var score = 0;
      score += notesArray.indexOf(note) != -1 ? 1 : 0;
      scale.int.forEach(function(noteInt) {
        // console.log(allnotes[convertIndex(noteInt + i)], scale)

        score += notesArray.indexOf(allnotes[convertIndex(noteInt + i)]) != -1 ? 1 : 0;

      });

      // you always keep the highest score (or scores)
      if (bestGuess[0].score < score) {

        bestGuess = [{
          score: score,
          key: note,
          type: scale.name
        }];
      } else if (bestGuess[0].score == score) {
        bestGuess.push({
          score: score,
          key: note,
          type: scale.name
        })
      }



    })
  })
  return bestGuess;

}


document.getElementById('showguess').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  notesArray = [];
  var chords = document.getElementById('chodseq').value.replace(/ /g,'').replace(/["']/g,'').split(',');
  chords.forEach(function(chord) {
    getNotesFromChords(chord)
  });
  var guesses = compareScalesAndNotes(notesArray);
  var alertText = "Probable key is:";
  guesses.forEach(function(guess, i) {
    alertText += (i > 0 ? " or " : " ") + guess.key + ' ' + guess.type;
  });
  
  alert(alertText)
  
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="chodseq" />

<button id="showguess">
Click to guess the key
</button>
```

For your example, it gives G major, that's because with a harmonic minor scale, there are no D major or Bm chords.

You can try easy ones: C, F, G or Eb, Fm, Gm

Or some with accidents: C, D7, G7 (this one will give you 2 guesses, because there's a real ambiguity, without giving more information, it could be both)

One with accidents but accurate: C, Dm, G, A

Comment: Am tempted to convert this to use Tonaljs, which would leverage the scale and chord interval knowledge of that library. P.S. Any idea why the current algorithm doesn't suggest `A minor` for the chords `'C', 'Dm', 'Em', 'F', 'G', 'Am'` - it only suggests `C major`?  Even the sequence `Am,C` doesn't suggest `A minor`?

Comment: @abulka it should work with tonaljs. As for the A minor not being suggested, it's simply that in the example, I'm using the harmonic minor scale, meaning that the 7th interval is major. The C chords in the harmonic minor is C with augmented fifth (C E G#), not C major (C E G). And the E is major, not minor. If you change the scale definition for the natural, so with a minor 7th (this way int: [2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10]), it should suggest A minor. But note that with this algorithm, the natural minor scale will always be suggested with its relative major because they are made of the same notes.

Comment: Switching to the natural minor scale intervals does indeed fix the problem. Presumably doing so is more "correct" since a key signature with no sharps or flats is indeed either C major or A minor. I think using the natural minor scale intervals in the way you suggest would mean the correct detection of all the other minor keys, too - though key detection from a wide variety of e.g. jazz chords may be more accurate using melodic minor intervals? not sure.

Comment: generally in classical or pop music it's the harmonic minor that is the "default" minor or at least when we say a song is in minor it generally means the harmonic. As for jazz, it may be a bit harder to get the key,  with the different modes and substitutions, etc.

Comment: Interesting - and a bit of googling adds this information: "Natural minor scales align with key signatures. Harmonic minor scales do not have corresponding key signatures, so composers indicate them using a combination of a key signature and a sharp accidental next to the seventh scale degree." P.S. The regular expression for 'major' in the above algorithm has a bug where e.g. `Bbm` will match as a major instead of a minor.  Here is an improved regex for major `reg: /^[A-G][M]?$|[A-G](?=[#b][M]?$)/`.

Answer (score 15):

The chords in a song of a particular key are *predominantly* members of the key's scale. I imagine you could get a good approximation statistically (if there is enough data) by comparing the predominant accidentals in the chords listed to the key signatures of the keys.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_fifths

Of course, a song in any key can/will have accidentals not in the keys scale, so it would likely be a statistical approximation. But over several bars, if you add up the accidentals and filter out all but the ones that occur most often, you may be able to match to a key signature.

Addendum: as Jonas w correctly points out, you may be able to get the signature, but you won't likely be able to determine if it is a major or minor key.

Comment: If you have the key signature you only have two options - major or minor. Pretty easy to figure out it is which given the chords

Comment: The Major and corresponding minor scales have the same chords, so I suppose if there is a predominance of minor chords in a piece - you could conclude it is in the minor key. Again, its an approximation I think.

Comment: The major and minor scale have difference chords - that's why they have different names, it's not just that they start on a different note. The harmonic and melodic minor scales share a minor third.  That minor third is not present in the major scale

Comment: @KScandrett the relative minor of a major has the same chords, in theory. 
For example A minor is the relative minor of C major. However, the 6th and 7th notes may be sharped (melodic or harmonic minor) resulting in some differences in scale. This depends upon usage.

Comment: @lurker and theres still not the *one* key in a song. Theres sometimes a *key change* ( weird translation :/)

Comment: @Jonasw yep, I mentioned that fact in my comments to the OPs question.

Answer (score 11):

Here's what I came up with. Still new with modern JS so apologies for messiness and bad use of map().

I looked around the internals of the tonal library, it has a function scales.detect(), but it was no good since it required every note present. Instead I used it as inspiration and flattened the progression into a simple note list and checked this in all transpositions as a subset of all the possible scales.

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const chord = require('tonal-chord');
const note = require('tonal-note');
const pcset = require('tonal-pcset');
const dictionary = require('tonal-dictionary');
const SCALES = require('tonal-scale/scales.json');
const dict = dictionary.dictionary(SCALES, function (str) { return str.split(' '); });

//dict is a dictionary of scales defined as intervals
//notes is a string of tonal notes eg 'c d eb'
//onlyMajorMinor if true restricts to the most common scales as the tonal dict has many rare ones
function keyDetect(dict, notes, onlyMajorMinor) {
    //create an array of pairs of chromas (see tonal docs) and scale names
    var chromaArray = dict.keys(false).map(function(e) { return [pcset.chroma(dict.get(e)), e]; });
    //filter only Major/Minor if requested
    if (onlyMajorMinor) { chromaArray = chromaArray.filter(function (e) { return e[1] === 'major' || e[1] === 'harmonic minor'; }); }
 //sets is an array of pitch classes transposed into every possibility with equivalent intervals
 var sets = pcset.modes(notes, false);

 //this block, for each scale, checks if any of 'sets' is a subset of any scale
 return chromaArray.reduce(function(acc, keyChroma) {
    sets.map(function(set, i) {
        if (pcset.isSubset(keyChroma[0], set)) {
            //the midi bit is a bit of a hack, i couldnt find how to turn an int from 0-11 into the repective note name. so i used the midi number where 60 is middle c
            //since the index corresponds to the transposition from 0-11 where c=0, it gives the tonic note of the key
            acc.push(note.pc(note.fromMidi(60+i)) + ' ' + keyChroma[1]);
            }
        });
        return acc;
    }, []);

    }

const p1 = [ chord.get('m','Bb'), chord.get('m', 'C'), chord.get('M', 'Eb') ];
const p2 = [ chord.get('M','F#'), chord.get('dim', 'B#'), chord.get('M', 'G#') ];
const p3 = [ chord.get('M','C'), chord.get('M','F') ];
const progressions = [ p1, p2, p3 ];

//turn the progression into a flat string of notes seperated by spaces
const notes = progressions.map(function(e) { return _.chain(e).flatten().uniq().value(); });
const possibleKeys = notes.map(function(e) { return keyDetect(dict, e, true); });

console.log(possibleKeys);
//[ [ 'Ab major' ], [ 'Db major' ], [ 'C major', 'F major' ] ]
```

Some drawbacks:
- doesn't give the enharmonic note you want necessarily. In p2, the more correct response is C# major, but this could be fixed by checking somehow with the original progression.
-‎ won't deal with 'decorations' to chords that are out of the key, which might occur in pop songs, eg. CMaj7 FMaj7 GMaj7 instead of C F G. Not sure how common this is, not too much I think.

Comment: `'tonal-scale/scales.json'` and `chord.get` don't seem to exist anymore.

Comment: This algorithm relies on an old `0.6.9` version of Tonaljs - we are up to `4.6.5` now in 2022. The two version of Tonaljs have incompatible APIs.  To get this algorithm to run, simply install the old version of Tonal viz. `npm install tonal-note@0.69.9`, `npm install tonal-chord@0.69.9` etc. etc.

Answer (score 8):

Given an array of tones like this:

```
var tones = ["G","Fis","D"];
```

We can firstly generate a unique Set of tones:

```
tones = [...new Set(tones)];
```

Then we could check for the appearence of # and bs :

```
var sharps = ["C","G","D","A","E","H","Fis"][["Fis","Cis","Gis","Dis","Ais","Eis"].filter(tone=>tones.includes(tone)).length];
```

Then do the same with bs and get the result with:

```
var key = sharps === "C" ? bs:sharps;
```

However, you still dont know if its *major* or *minor*, and many componists do not care of the upper rules (and changed the key inbetween )...

Answer (score 7):

You might be able too keep an structure with keys for every "supported" scale, with as value an array with chords matching that scale.

Given a chord progression you can then start by making a shortlist of keys  based on your structure.

With multiple matches you can try to make an educated guess. For example, add other "weight" to any scale that matches the root note.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the spiral array, a 3D model for tonality created by Elaine Chew, which has a key detection algorithm.

*Chuan, Ching-Hua, and Elaine Chew. "[Polyphonic audio key finding using the spiral array CEG algorithm](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f9ba/63cbcc3e401b22a735593ee772402eb58a90.pdf)." Multimedia and Expo, 2005. ICME 2005. IEEE International Conference on. IEEE, 2005.*

My recent tension model, which is available in a [.jar file here](http://dorienherremans.com/tension), also outputs the key (in addition to the tension measures) based on the spiral array. It can either take a musicXML file or text file as input that just takes a list of pitch names for each 'time window' in your piece.

*Herremans D., Chew E..  2016.  [Tension ribbons: Quantifying and visualising tonal tension](http://dorienherremans.com/sites/default/files/paper_tenor_dh_preprint_small.pdf). Second International Conference on Technologies for Music Notation and Representation (TENOR). 2:8-18.*

Answer (score 1):

If you're not opposed to switching languages, music21 (my library, disclaimer) in Python would do this:

```
from music21 import stream, harmony

chordSymbols = ['Cm', 'Dsus2', 'E-/C', 'G7', 'Fm', 'Cm']
s = stream.Stream()
for cs in chordSymbols:
    s.append(harmony.ChordSymbol(cs))
s.analyze('key')
```

Returns: `<music21.key.Key of c minor>`

The system will know the difference between, say C# major and Db major.  It has a full vocabulary of chord names so things like "Dsus2" won't confuse it.  The only thing that might bite a newcomer is that flats are written with minus signs so "E-/C" instead of "Eb/C"

Comment: Interesting, why did you go with `-` instead of `b`?

Comment: There are many contexts where a note/key or accidental could be used and so it avoids the ambiguity of whether `b` is a note or key (b minor) or a flat sign.

Comment: The above snippet always returns `b minor` no matter what chords are entered. Turns out you have to set the length of time for each chord symbol to something - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59010500/music21-analyze-key-always-returns-c-minor

Comment: Ah. That changed in the latest version. Yes, now you’ll need to set a duration or “displayAsChord”

Answer (score -2):

There is an online free tool (MazMazika Songs Chord Analyzer), which analyzes and detects the chords of any song very fast. You can process the song through file upload (MP3/WAV) or by pasting YouTube / SoundCloud links. After processing the file, you can play the song while seeing all the chords playing along in-real time, as well as a table containing all the chords, each chord is assigned to a time-position & a number ID, which you can click to go directly to the corresponding chord and it`s time-position.

https://www.mazmazika.com/chordanalyzer

Comment: There are many tools to detect chords from notes - that’s not the issue. This question is about detecting the key from a progression of chords, which MazMazika does not address.